# Complete uninstall of Postgresql from Mac OSX problems

Tags: database, macos, postgresql, uninstallation

Initially I wanted to uninstall PSQL from my system and switch to postgres app, version 9.2.

Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037729/completely-uninstall-postgresql-9-0-4-from-mac-osx-lion) guide closely, but still have problems with postgresql being active on my system.

psql gives me

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

When I got to

```
rm /usr/bin/psql
```

I get

```
override rwxr-xr-x root/wheel compressed for /usr/bin/psql?
```

Since this is out of my competencies, and I have no idea what it does, I am asking you guys.

Comment: How did you determine that "postgresql being active on my system"?

Comment: because psql command is still functioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files in `/usr/bin` are a part of your operating system, and among the numerous suppliers of PostgreSQL installers or packages for Mac OS X, I think none of them ever suggests to delete `/usr/bin/psql`.

In fact there are quite a few more files that you would delete, should you want to wipe out the PostgreSQL client layer as shipped by Apple. And when you'll upgrade that system to `10.8.X+1` or whatever, the Apple installer may well put them back again with newer versions.

If you're in uncharted territory when playing admin with your operating system, it's better to just follow the procedure suggested on [postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/documentation), which boils down to changing your program's search path, so that their `psql` and other tools (`pg_dump`, `pg_restore`,...) come first.

Also, related answer: [How to fix pg_dump version mismatch errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168920/how-to-fix-pg-dump-version-mismatch-error)