# Heroku pg_dump version mismatch

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku-postgres

I am stuck with an error trying to push a database to `heroku`

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.3.3; pg_dump version: 9.1.9
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
pg_dump: *** aborted because of error
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
```

I have tried making additions to my `PATH` as described in other questions, and I have installed 9.3.3 using the package as described on the `heroku` doc page. But no luck so far.

Comment: Are you using PG admin? If so, make sure you open the proper PG admin version. Many pg admin can coexist at the same time and they use pd_dump of their install version.

Comment: Not sure what pgadmin is lol.. I am using the command line on my mac. I installed pg from the package on the website

Comment: What's the output of `pg_dump --version` and `which pg_dump`?

Comment: pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 9.1.9 and /usr/bin/pg_dump

Comment: It's a mismatch with your pg_dump version. Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168920/how-to-fix-pg-dump-version-mismatch-errors. PGAdmin is really useful little app, it is available for OSx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to remove pg_dump from the two existing installations on the system and copy over the dump from the .app package installation, I found this location from the documentation on the website. This fixed the issue for me.

Comment: How did you remove? Any guidance please.,.