# fixing path pg_dump mistmatch errors

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to dump my postgres database using pg_dump.  When I execute the command I get the following error:

```
pg_dump: server version: 9.5rc1; pg_dump version: 9.4.5
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

I understand there a fair amount of quality answers to this question such as:

[How to fix pg_dump version mismatch errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168920/how-to-fix-pg-dump-version-mismatch-errors)

These answers say that I should change the path to postgres using

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

I don't really understand where I should put code such as this or exactly what it is doing.  I would really like to know how this works conceptually.

Comment: Area you working on Mac? how did you install PostgreSql? Infos about the PATH variables can you find here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29

Comment: Yes, working on Mac.  I installed Postgres through EnterpriseDB.  Thanks for the link @TommasoDiBucchianico