# Pg dump version different from server error - docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, macos-mojave, pg-dump

I know this is an old question that has several answers on the web. I have been following the thread [How to fix pg_dump version mismatch errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168920/how-to-fix-pg-dump-version-mismatch-errors) But none of them seems to be working.

Issue:

```
pg_dump: error: server version: 14.5 (Debian 14.5-2.pgdg110+2); pg_dump version: 13.1
```

Additional info:

```
pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 13.1

which pg_dump
/usr/local/bin/pg_dump

echo $PATH
/Users/prajeeshb/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin:/Users/prajeeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0/bin:/Users/prajeeshb/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.0@global/bin:/Users/prajeeshb/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.0/bin:/Users/prajeeshb/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

I am using mac and i tried to put this at the top of .profile file

```
export PATH="/Applications/PostgreSQL\ 10/pgAdmin\ 4.app/Contents/MacOS/applet:$PATH"
```

and then run

```
. ~/.profile
```

and then opening a new window and run `rails db:migrate`, i am getting the same version mismatch error.

Any idea on how to fix this?

PS: I am running postgres on docker

Comment: Put the correct directory first in your path. I cannot tell you where you installed the binaries for PostgreSQL v14.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am running postgres on docker. Is there any command to find the binary installation path?

Comment: Sorry; you have to know where you installed PostgreSQL. I have no access to your machine.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: the path is /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/13.1

Comment: But that's probably version 13. You need a `pg_dump` in version 14.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe i am using docker to run postgres. I have pulled an image recently and then issue occurs. The postgres that i have installed on my machine is only version 13. Is there anything that i am missing?

Comment: Install version 14 on the machine.